# subprocess check_output getting standard output: Broken pipe warning message

Tags: python, python-2.7, subprocess

I have below command which executes Just fine when I am trying in Linux SuSE OS(I mean any warnings):

```
   supportconfig -R /tmp
```

Same command I used in python using subprocess check_output

Code:

```
import os
import sys
from subprocess import check_output
b = check_output(["supportconfig", "-R", "/tmp"])
```

Warning Output:

```
sort: write error
sort: write failed: standard output: Broken pipe
sort: write error
grep: write error
```

Same code will be used for reproduce issue in Open SuSE or SLES OS.

Comment: The shell suppresses any *Broken pipe* messages. But we can't really tell what's wrong without seeing the source of the script which produces these messages.

Comment: supportconfig command comes in suse and using same code we can reproduce issue.

Comment: I found the SUSE pages but they don't reveal the purpose of the `/tmp` argument. If this is a shell script, can you run it with `bash -x /usr/bin/supportconfig -m /tmp` (guessing the path) to see what commands exactly produce these errors?

Comment: @tripleee, By default logs are generated in /var/log if you do not want this directory to use the you can use any path in this case  /tmp .How ever I am trying your suggestions

Comment: @triplee, There is no such errors when I am using bash (bash -x /sbin/supportconfig -m /tmp)

Comment: What if you run that from within Python?

Comment: I just moved warning message to null